# Confusion in comparing string with a number in php

Tags: php

This is my code

```
        $preference = '151000';
        $range = 'above';
        if($preference <= $range){
            echo "Yes"; die;
        }else{
            echo "No"; die;
        }
```

This provides 'Yes', i want to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it in the php manual. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

When comparing a string, number or resource with another string, number or resource:

> Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math

Btw: '151000' is a string, not a number. 15100 would be a number.

Answer (score 1):

Here you basically compare two strings and php uses their ASCII codes to compare them. The first symbol 1 is lower than 'a'.

If you want to compare two strings properly, use function:

```
strcmp()
```

If you want compare different types, you can read about  [PHP type comparison tables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).